# Count and sum up duplicate records in a file (UNIX)

Tags: bash, unix

I supposed to count the total the duplicate records in a file.

I used

```
 sort $TEMP_FILE2 | uniq -d
```

to list all duplicate records without count. My problem is, i do not know what script to use to sum up or get the total of those records.

This should be my output:

Total Data Count: xxx

**Duplicate Data Count: xxx** (Total duplicate records in a file)

Final Data Count: xxx

Comment: You could use `awk`.  Without some sample data, it's unlikely for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: This should work: `awk '你吃饭了吗你多吃一点慢慢吃慢走我先走了' inputFile`

Comment: @jaypal Does your `awk` expression *really* contain [Chinese characters](http://i.imgur.com/9kCw0MV.png), or are my (or your) browser fonts messed up?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma 对 which means, yes, thats correct! `:P`

Comment: @jaypal I think I missed that part of the awk manpage ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'll take a few guesses here, since its not entirely clear what's needed.  First I'll assume your file looks something like this:

```
apple
banana
pear
apple
pear
apple
```

I assume *"Total Data Count"* is simply the number of entries, i.e. the total number of lines in the file.  `wc -l` is the tool for that:

```
$ echo "Total Data Count: $(wc -l < temp_file)"
Total Data Count: 6
$
```

Then *"Duplicate Data Count"* is one of two things:

If it is the count of all records that are duplicated (5 = "apple", "apple", "apple", "banana", "banana" in my example), `uniq -dc` to get counts of duplicated fields, then `awk` to sum them up:

```
$ echo "Duplicate Data Count: $(sort temp_file | uniq -dc | awk '{count+=$1} END {print count}')"
Duplicate Data Count: 5
$
```

If it is the number of records that contain duplicates (but not full count of all duplicates) (2 = "apple", "banana" in my example), then `wc -l` of `uniq -d` should be sufficient:

```
$ echo "Duplicate Data Count: $(sort temp_file | uniq -d | wc -l)"
Duplicate Data Count: 2
$
```

I'm assuming *"Final Data Count"* is the number of all records with duplicates removed (3 = "apple", "pear", "banana" in my example).  Here we can just pipe plain `uniq` to `wc -l`:

```
$ echo "Final Data Count: $(sort temp_file | uniq | wc -l)"
Final Data Count: 3
$
```

Comment: this works "Duplicate Data Count: $(sort temp_file | uniq -d | wc -l)" thanks :)